# ion-fab in ion-footer always under ion-content

Tags: ionic-framework, layout, sass, ionic3

I added 2 ion-fab buttons in my the ion-footer of my page, but the problem here is that it looks like they are after the ion-content...
I tried to add a crazy z-index, but it's not working....
What did I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Leander

[image]

```html
<ion-footer class="footer-section flex justify-center items-center">
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-fab left class="icon icon-search">
        <button ion-fab (click)="searchProduct()">
          <svg class="icon icon--search">
            <use xlink:href="assets/icon/magazijnapp-icons.svg#icon-search"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </ion-fab>
      <ion-fab right class="icon icon-qrcode">
        <button ion-fab (click)="scanProduct()">
          <svg class="icon icon--qrcode">
            <use xlink:href="assets/icon/magazijnapp-icons.svg#icon-qrcode"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </ion-fab>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use `ion-footer` instead? Are there items under `ion-footer` aside these fabs?

Comment: As Ion-footer always stay in bottom of the screen after ion-content so it will always show like this if you want it above footer you need to remove it from footer tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have use `ion-fab` direct after `ion-content` and use `left bottom` & `right bottom` attributes in ion-fab

```
<ion-content>
...
</ion-content>

</ion-content>
<ion-fab left bottom class="icon icon-search">
    <button ion-fab (click)="searchProduct()">
        <svg class="icon icon--search">
            <use xlink:href="assets/icon/magazijnapp-icons.svg#icon-search"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
</ion-fab>
<ion-fab right bottom class="icon icon-qrcode">
    <button ion-fab (click)="scanProduct()">
        <svg class="icon icon--qrcode">
            <use xlink:href="assets/icon/magazijnapp-icons.svg#icon-qrcode"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
</ion-fab>
```